# Javascript pass option to variable and save to txt file with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, load, save

We are making progress with this and I really do appreciate the help.

I have a page where you can choose from a few different options for background images.  When you click an option it updates the background in realtime (which is nice), but what I want to do now is be able to -save- the option you click so its there when you visit the page after closing the browser.

I can't use database (its at work) so I'm trying to save the option you pick to a local text file that can be loaded when you visit the site.  Here is the code that drives the options in its purest form:

```
var $bg = new Array(); // don't change this
var $choice = "";

$bg[0] = "";
$bg[1] = "images/bg3.png";
$bg[2] = "images/bgStyle_cheetah.png";

function changeBGImage(img) {
if (document.body) {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+$bg[img]+")"; }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<A href="javascript:changeBGImage(0)">1</A>
<A href="javascript:changeBGImage(1)">2</A>
<A href="javascript:changeBGImage(2)">3</A>
</body>
```

How can I motify this so that when submitted the page will save the choice and how can I load those settings back in?  I know I need a submit button of some kind but should it be type=button or type=submit or what?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason you aren't using a cookie for this?

Comment: Well, apparently I don't know how to do that...I am trying to logically work this out based on what I know, so any guidance on this is appreciated.

Comment: if you want to use a submit button, to save its generally linked to a form with `input type="submit"`. however, since you want to load for a local user, you really should be using a cookie/localstorage, as javascript/php in general cannot read files off a the user's computer

Comment: I understand, so what shall I search for incorporating the use of a cookie/localStorage to the code i already have?

Answer (score 0):

An option is working with an Ajax request. For example with [Microajax library](https://code.google.com/p/microajax/)

Example:

**Javascript:**

```
function changeBGImage(img) {
    if(document.body){
        microAjax("script.php?image_id="+img, function (res) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+$bg[img]+")";
        });
    }
}
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
    $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];
    $file = "my_image_option.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $image_id);
?>
```